# how do sum the list object values with null value in java?

Tags: java

I have list with null value. How to sum in java. While am sum, getting null value exception.

I have the list like,

```
Double list = { null, 113.43, 11.5, 25.6}
```

getting list from object.

How can i sum and display in console in java?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have an Object array (which contains null or Double).

```
double result = 0;
for(Object o: list){
   if(o instanceof Double){
        Double v = (Double) o;
        result += v;
   }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider avoiding doing *any* kind of arithmetic on such an array as it's difficult to define the behaviour when `null` entries are encountered.

For a *sum*, you could make the obvious and tractable assumption that `null` counts as zero, which yields the code

```
for (Double element : list) {
    result += element == null ? 0.0 : element;
}
```

But what should the behaviour be for say the *mean*? Does `null` count in the number of elements? Deciding on how the *variance* is defined is harder still.

If I were you I'd ensure that the given array was more carefully defined. Throwing a `NullPointerException` is possibly the safest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do :

```
Double sum = 0.0;
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
for(Double value : list ) {
               sum = sum+value.doubleValue();  
    }
```

Comment: I would assume that we want to get the sum of all non-null elements. What this code does, is getting either the sum of list with no nulls or exception.

Comment: @PhamTrung the power of Edit, I commented on an entirely different code

Comment: @Deltharis yes your comment was totally valid before I posted this edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check this way:

```
    Double[] list = {null, 113.43, 11.5, 25.6};
    double result = 0;

    for (Double element : list) {
        if (null != element) {
            result += element;
        }
    }
```

Note that you have an array of `Double` objects. But in the loop you use:

```
result += element;
```

which logically equals to

```
result = result + element;
```

According to the autoboxing/unboxing feature of java you do not need to call: `element.doubleValue();` in the expression. Java will extract double value from the processing `Double` object and add it to `result` variable.